# Slice 2nd half of data frame in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I can easily slice the 1st half (or any other percentage) of a data frame using:

```
library(dplyr)    

df <- data.frame(x = 1:10)

df %>% 
  slice(seq(0.5 * n()))
```

However, how can I slice the 2nd half of my data frame?

Comment: `df[nrow(df)/2:nrow(df),]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With negative indices

```
library(dplyr)    

df <- data.frame(x = 1:10)

df %>% 
  slice(-seq(0.5 * n()))
```

Answer (score 4):

`slice()` can do two things: keep rows if you give it positive row numbers, or drop rows if you give it negative row numbers. You can use either of these to grab the second half of your dataframe:

```
# Keeping later rows
df %>% slice(seq(n()/2, n()))

# Dropping earlier rows
df %>% slice(-seq(1, n()/2))
```

You'll want to be careful if you have an odd number of rows, since `n()/2` won't be an integer in those cases. Using `seq(0.5 * n())` as in your example could run into this problem too. To be safe, you can be explicit about how to handle the middle cases with `floor()` and `ceiling()`:

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:11)

# Include row 5
df %>% slice(seq(floor(n()/2), n()))

# Exclude row 5
df %>% slice(seq(ceiling(n()/2), n()))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also just slightly modify your `seq` argument:

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:10)

df %>% 
  slice(seq(n() * 0.5, n()))
```

Update per @Kerry Jackson's suggestion:

```
df %>% 
  slice(seq(floor(n() * 0.5) + 1, n()))
```

if an odd number of rows - you'll need to select how to deal with the middle row.

Comment: I think this is not exactly as asked for, and instead should be `df %>% 
  slice(seq(from = n()/2 + 1, to = n()))`

Comment: sure - my answer was mostly to indicate you can modify the argument to `slice` to fit the window you want to see, but your suggestion is likely more accurate.